# Programmatically report if ACL support is enable in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, acl

I am building a server install script and want to to check if ACL support has been enabled before setting directory default permissions.

The `getfacl` manpage states:

> If getfacl is used on a file system that does not support ACLs, getfacl displays the access permissions defined by the traditional file mode permission bits.

I would rather not hack together a umask comparison, etc., but haven't discovered a better option anywhere.

Thoughts?

**EDIT: I should include this is being attempted on CentOS 6.4 systems**

Comment: Maybe. Try something like `cat /proc/fs/ext4/sda1/options | grep acl`

Comment: This is exactly the angle I'm looking for. However, there's nothing analogous to an `options` file in the `/proc/fs/<fs_type>` directories

Comment: Look under the drive under fs_type.

Comment: Yeah, nothing but `mb_groups` for all my partitions. (See my edit above.)

Comment: I don't see any pending edit(s), but I checked on an Ubuntu 12.04. It might be easier to create a temp file and try to set an ACL on it. That won't work if the FS doesn't support ACLs.

Comment: That is one of my options, but ends up proving a negative instead of a positive (like your first suggestion does). There are a few non-ideal solutions available. I'm just trying to avoid them unless necessary. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DIRECTORY="/home"
MOUNTPOINT=`df "$DIRECTORY" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`
MOUNTSET=`/sbin/tune2fs -l $MOUNTPOINT | grep "Default mount options" | grep acl | wc -l`
if [ "$MOUNTSET" = "0" ]; then
     echo "Mount point $MOUNTPOINT does not have enabled ACL."
else
     echo "Juppi. Mount point $MOUNTPOINT have enabled ACL."
fi
```

Works fine on Debian 7.